# Setting an environment variable with part of another environment variable in a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, set, environment

I am looking to set a new environment variable as the last two digits of the year, once the year has already been defined.

At the moment I have :

```
set Year=2013
set Yr=13
```

But I want the user to only have to update Year each time they use it and have the batch file key off of Year to define Yr.

Thanks for your help,
Catherine

Comment: please provide some code or xml to get more information

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set Year=2013
set /a Yr=Year-2000
echo %Yr%
```

Output:

```
13
```

Comment: Or `Set Yr=%Year:~-2%` .. which is Y3K compliant :)

Comment: Yes. Or `for /f "tokens=2delims=0" %%i in ("%year%") do set Yr=%%i`